# Model of human estimation of correlation tasks

Tags: perception, vision, correlation, sensory-perception

I am looking for a model (bayesian or not) on how people would estimate the correlation between two variables from a given scatter plot. Any one knows of such model?

Comment: Can you share some links on  how people would estimate the correlation between two variables from a given scatter plot? thanks.

Comment: Related question http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/16120/11318